# Removing object reference in Java from multiple locations

Tags: java

I have a class like this:

```
Class Node {
   private String name;
   private Node next;

   public Node(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void setNext(Node node) {
      this.next = node;
   }

   public Node getNext() {
      return this.next;
   }
}
```

I have a sample node:

```
Node node = new Node("abc");
Node n1 = new Node("def");

node.setNext(n1);
```

Now if I do:

```
n1 = null;
node.getNext()  <--  This returns new Node("def");
```

How can I make it return `null` without using the `setNext()` method. I have a list of `Node` objects and if I remove any `Node` object from the list, I want to set all the `next` pointers to null that pointed to the deleted node.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: *You* have to keep track of references to an object. The JVM doesn't do that. What you're asking cannot be done. You could theoretically encapsulate the reference, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: There's basically no way to do this (certainly not literally when nulling a field), and it also looks like mis-design to me.  Not understanding how OOP works, and an X-Y problem too.  If you can tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to make some suggestions.  (It "can" be done, via a method call, as Andreas points out, but the result would be so mind-boggling and evil I can't imagine it would be useful or maintainable.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without setting it using setNext why ??
because node still has the value of n1 so you have to set node.setNext to null also .... If you wish to set all the next pointers to null from the deleted node then you have to loop the whole thing till the end and set each of them to null.

If you want,you can set it in the model class, but you have to still use setNode

Comment: I was looking for an efficient way of doing it. I find Looping through the entire list inefficient.

Comment: Actually you can just set only node.setNext(null), then this node will have no reference to the other nodes thereby preventing you to having to set the other nodes values to NULL but... BUT it will create a list node which are useless and memory occupying bunch  haha....you can use @John Mclane (killer name :P) and call it recursively end of the day its basically looping :P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without setting next to null by calling setNext, because

Node node = new Node("abc");
Node n1 = new Node("def");

node.setNext(n1); --> now both n1 and next will be pointing to same object in heap.

n1 = null; --> this will make n1 point to null but next will still be pointing to the Node object in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do if `getNext()` is called more often than `setNext(...)` (as usually the case):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Node {
    private String name;
    private Node next;
    private static final Map<Node, Set<Node>> backLinks = new HashMap<>();

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNext(Node node) {
        if (node == next)
            return;
        Set<Node> usedIn;
        if (next != null) {
            usedIn = backLinks.get(next);
            usedIn.remove(this);
        }
        if (node != null) {
            usedIn = backLinks.get(node);
            if (usedIn == null) {
                usedIn = new HashSet<>();
                backLinks.put(node, usedIn);
            }
            usedIn.add(this);
        }
        next = node;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    // call this whenever you need to invalidate (exclude) a node
    public static void invalidate(Node node) {
        Set<Node> usedIn = backLinks.get(node);
        if (usedIn == null)
            return;
        for (Node n : usedIn)
            n.next = null;
        backLinks.remove(node);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node = new Node("abc");
        Node n1 = new Node("def");
        node.setNext(n1);
        System.out.println(node.getNext());
        invalidate(n1);
        n1 = null; // optional
        System.out.println(node.getNext());
    }
}
```

Otherwise, keep a collection of all valid nodes and query it every time you call `getNext()`. Change the line

```
private static final Map<Node, Set<Node>> backLinks = new HashMap<>();
```

to

```
private static final Set<Node> validNodes = new HashSet<>();
```

And also change the constructor and next three methods:

```
    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        validNodes.add(this);
    }

    public void setNext(Node node) {
        next = node;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return validNodes.contains(next) ? next : null;
    }

    // call this whenever you need to invalidate (exclude) a node
    public static void invalidate(Node node) {
        validNodes.remove(node);
    }
```

Also, you may want to add the following lines to the end of `invalidate` method in both cases:

```
if (node.next != null)
    invalidate(node.next);
```

This will effectively remove the whole chain linked to the node being invalidated via recursive call.